# Configure a .NET program to throw an exception if a setting isn't found?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to transparently configure a .NET application to throw an exception when you try to access a setting which doesn't exist (e.g. Properties.Settings.Default.xyz)?  I just killed an day troubleshooting a program that was producing whacky results for a user only to discover that he was missing the .config file.  I was astounded to discover that .NET simply assigns a default value if a setting is missing rather than throwing an exception!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it is good practice in many cases to validate inputs of a class, of a function, of a query, etc... . Better to fail early than to generate useless results for the consumer of your app, or - worse - late errors due to those useless and wacky results.

So, if you can validate the inputs of your whole program (and settings are sort of inputs of your program), especially if you know that this would cause many things to fail or some other problems later :

### **It is a good idea to validate and fail early**

Now, it's just logic to implement, it's simply part of your program algorithm. It is something you should do manually at the beginning, there's IMHO no special pattern or .NET class / option involved, apart for the one you are already using to read your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I can definitely think of a hundred different ways to handle this type of thing manually, but it just seems odd to me that .NET wouldn't be designed to, for instance, throw a NullReferenceException if you try to read a setting that isn't available.  How could just using a default value & hoping for the best be a good design choice (for the .NET framework itself as opposed to an individual program)?

Comment: My guess is that, the 'default' behavior is that some obscure rarely used setting should not make your program crash in production if the developper forgot to null-check it.
 (causing the hated "*This program has stopped working... Windows looking for a solution...*"). A freshly installed program may not have (some) settings initialized. Some program may have a lot of 'optional' settings, that don't need initialization until they are first used. IMO it's just to give a 'default impression' of robustness and graceful handling of various edge cases.

Comment: also, some user or other software on user-side could mess with the settings, they are not in control of your software at every point in time. So, by default, it is not so bad as a decision to prevent crashing from a change that you don't have full control on, as a developper.

Answer (score 0):

Configure, no. Die, yes.

In your class constructor for main, read all the settings and check them for validity. Log and throw if any are not. The program will die hard. Read the log to find out which setting is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a missing `app.config` as a missing `web.config` would cause your web app to show a horrible message. If this is a windows application then perhaps you might want to think about embedding your settings in a way that a missing configuration would not cripple it. The easiest way to do what you are asking with an `app.config` file is to create a function to read a value and send in what you ideally think is the best default value at the time when not overridden. If you can ascertain that the configuration has become corrupt then alert a user at startup but allow a way to return to default state, if you can.